# sshd, password for local network, keys for external interface

Tags: authentication, passwords, openssh, sshd

Is there any easy way to set `sshd_config` (for opensshd 6.7) options in a way that  I can use passwords on connections from 192.168.* network, but restrict authentication to key only from everywhere else?

I trust my firewall enough that i won't have external connections coming in sporting IPs in that range as the source, and I am willing to bet on that for the convenience of using passwords in the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `Match` block available in ssh_config, where you can set up IP addresses and subnets:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Match Address 192.168.0.0/16
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```